# Escaping multiple illegal characters in params

Tags: java, batch-file

I have to put this param on the run.bat file :

..@n9D'"BcnYx+Yj^=%X

how can i read this arg from my java code ? and escaping all these illegal characters?

thank you for helping

Comment: Why do you think you have to escape anything?

Comment: Creating a `test.bat` with just the line `@echo %1` and running it with `test.bat ..@n9D'"BcnYx+Yj^=%X` results in output `..@n9D'"BcnYx+Yj^=%X`. So I repeat the question of [Sotirios Delimanolis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis). Why do you think you have to escape anything?